# Is it possible to change the Vec entity property?

Tags: rust

I have a basic Rust `Vec` object named `MenuResponse`. The code looks like this:

```
#[get("/v1/role/menu")]
pub fn get_role_menu_tree() -> content::Json<String> {
    let menu_responses:Vec<MenuResponse> = menu_query_full_tree::<Vec<MenuResource>>(&request);
    let menu_vec:Vec<DynamicMenuResponse> = admin_user_menus(login_user_info);
    for mut menu_res in menu_responses {
        let ids:Vec<i32> = menu_vec.iter()
            .map(|item| item.id)
            .collect();
        if ids.contains(&menu_res.id){
            menu_res.checked = true;
        }
    }
    return box_rest_response(menu_responses);
}
```

The `MenuResponse` is defined like this:

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub struct MenuResponse {
    pub id: i32,
    pub name: String,
    pub res_type: i32,
    pub created_time: i64,
    pub updated_time: i64,
    pub remark: Option<String>,
    pub path: Option<String>,
    pub parent_id: i32,
    pub sort: i32,
    pub checked: bool,
    pub children: Vec<MenuResponse>
}
```

I want to change each element in the `Vec<MenuResponse>`'s property, in Java. In Java we can just set the value for each element. What should I do for an equivalent behavior in Rust? It seems I have to new `Vec` and put an element with the new value for each element? What should I do to change the `menu_responses:Vec` element property without creating a new Vec?

Comment: What's the problem with the code you have? If it doesn't compile, please post the compiler message. If it compiles but does not do what you expect, please explain the observed and expected behaviour.

Comment: You probably want `for menu_res in menu_responses.iter_mut()`. Also I'd recommend moving the `let ids = menu_vec.iter()` iteration outside the loop body, since it will be the same every time.

Comment: Why do you need to `collect()` identifiers in a new vector that you only use for searching? You can just `menu_vec.iter().find(|&&m| m.id == menu_res.id)`. This way you also early stop when you find the necessary element, not traversing the whole vector

Comment: thank you for point it out, I am still learning rust.@AlexeyLarionov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`iter_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter_mut) to get `&mut T` of the `Vec<T>` elements:

```rust
#[get("/v1/role/menu")]
pub fn get_role_menu_tree() -> content::Json<String> {
    let mut menu_responses:Vec<MenuResponse> = menu_query_full_tree::<Vec<MenuResource>>(&request);
    let menu_vec:Vec<DynamicMenuResponse> = admin_user_menus(login_user_info);
    let ids:Vec<i32> = menu_vec.iter()
        .map(|item| item.id)
        .collect();
    for menu_res in menu_responses.iter_mut() {
        if ids.contains(&menu_res.id){
            menu_res.checked = true;
        }
    }
    return box_rest_response(menu_responses);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9af412f9599ef889900ac7d9a5a54165) example